# OpenCV2.4.0 - facerec_demo runtime error

Tags: opencv

I am new to OpenCV. I am specifically exploring Face recognition capabilities added in OpenCV2.4beta version. After compiling and executing `samples/cpp/facerec_demo.cpp`, I get following runtime error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F) in cvtColor, file /home/truptivk/Desktop/Face Recognition /OpenCV-2.4.0-beta2/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3143
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/truptivk/Desktop/Face Recognition /OpenCV-2.4.0-beta2/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3143: error: (-215) depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After dumping the depth value it shows `CV_64F`.

I have created csvfile.ext for AT&T database. (Images have 8-bit grey levels.) and I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit version. I am clueless from where its picking up `CV_64`F.

Please help me to rectify this error. What needs to be one in order to avoid this?
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got in touch with Philipp Wagner, who has written the face recognition code. I received a reply from him.

> His Reply: A small bug happened while it was ported to OpenCV 2.4.
>   I'll fix it in the SVN as soon as I find the time. For now I have
>   uploaded a corrected facerec_demo.cpp for OpenCV 2.4
>   [here](http://bytefish.de/dev/cpp/facerec_demo.cpp)

So on this note, I am closing this thread.
@karlphillip Thanks a lot for all you help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use 2.4Beta which is not an **official/stable** release, so I suggest you request help on OpenCV mailing list.

If you are considering using the official [2.4.0 release](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/show/tags/2.4.0) you can grab it's sources and compile it yourself.

It's not on the website yet, but you can find it in the repositories.

Comment: thanks @karlphillip. I downloaded 2.4.0 release. But I am still facing the same issue :(

Comment: You might have better results if you share the CSV file you are using. Also, [check this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9227461/176769).

Comment: Face recognition is a newly added functionality and there is very little ref material available. I am referring to the blogs written by Philipp Wagner (He has added this functionality to OpenCV)
I have created a csvfile as mentioned at the [link](http://www.bytefish.de/blog/opencv_visual_studio_and_libfacerec). I downloaded the AT&T database and updated cvs file with my directory path.

Comment: In other words, anyone trying to help you will have to go through a lot of work just to be able to reproduce the problem you are facing. I suggest that this question be closed until you are prepared to edit the question and share a package with all the necessary files to reproduce the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I do understand its lot of work but I was hoping to find somebody who has encountered similar problem while using OpenCV.

Comment: Hi All, I got in touch with Philipp Wagner, who has written the face recognition code. I received a reply from him.

His Reply:
A small bug happened while it was ported to OpenCV 2.4. I'll fix it in the SVN as soon as I find the time. For now I have uploaded a corrected facerec_demo.cpp for OpenCV 2.4 [here](http://bytefish.de/dev/cpp/facerec_demo.cpp)

Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: Excellent. You should add a new answer with this info and accept it.